# Проблема с добавлением печенек в фильтре/сервлете

Tags: java, cookie, jsp, auth, filter

При авторизации пользователя создаются печеньки:
Есть главная страница - index.jsp
Есть домашняя страница, куда попадают после авторизации - home.jsp
Есть Фильтр, который завязан на home.jsp.
Авторизация происходит в фильтре(через класс идёт подключение к бд) и если всё успешно то создаются печеньки и дальше всё переходит к home.jsp. В home.jsp в самом начале идёт проверка на печеньки и если они есть то юзер остаётся на странице, если нет делаю Redirect на index.jsp.

Суть проблемы в том что после выхода из Фильтра печенек нет. После него идёт проверка в home.jsp и соотвецтвенно он перенаправляет на index а там уже печеньки появляются и он перенаправляет на home. Так же само если делать это всё через Сервлен

Вопрос как такое лечить? знаю вариант это добавлять куки уже на самой home странице.

Код добавления в куки:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("login", Login);

cookie.setMaxAge(CookiesTime);

res.addCookie(cookie);
```

Проверка на куки в home.jsp

```
<%
    String login = "";
    String hash = "";

    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if (cookie.getName().equals("badAuth")) {
            System.err.println("home.jsp -> Found badAuth!");

            response.sendRedirect("index");
            return;
        } else {
            if (cookie.getName().equals("login")) {
                System.out.println("home.jsp -> Found login");
                login = cookie.getValue();
            }
            if (cookie.getName().equals("hash")) {
                System.out.println("home.jsp -> Found hash");
                hash = cookie.getValue();
            }
        }
    }

    dbConnect connect = new dbConnect();

    if (!login.equals("") && !hash.equals("")) {
        if (connect.checkHash(login, hash)) {

            int roleNum = connect.checkUserRole(login, dbConnect.ROLE_USER);
            if(roleNum == 1 || roleNum == 2) {
                request.setAttribute("role", roleNum);

                ArrayList<Link> linkArr = connect.GetLinks(connect.getId(login));
                request.setAttribute("linkArr", linkArr);
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("index");
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("index");
        return;
    }
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
html страница...
```

Comment: Приведите кусок исходного текста программы, где проверяется наличие печенья. И вообще перенаправлять в случае отсутствия печенек лучше в фильтре, а не в home.jsp

Comment: А как быть с остальными фильтрами? которые есть в цепочке.. их выбросить что ли?
перенаправлять в фильтре не совсем правильно, но можно.

Обновил первый пост, сюда не влезает.

Comment: `res.addCookie(cookie);` - как понимаю добавление печеньки в ответ (response)? А `cookies = request.getCookies();` получить печеньку из запроса? Фильтр складывает в ответ. jsp ищет в запросе. И не находит, потому что запрос был без печеньки, а фильтр положил её в ответ. Сделайте так, что бы фильтр ещё и в запрос её кидал (пуст все думают что она там была всегда) `res.addCookie(...); req.addCookie(...);`

Comment: Какой смысл в других фильтрах, если авторизация не пройдена?

Comment: @Sergey у _req_ нет метода добавления печенек. 
Песеньки чудным образом появляются при переадресации из home в index, тобишь в index у нас печеньки уже есть, те что добавляли в фильтре.

По большому счёту смысла нет, но нарушать всё это тоже не есть хорошо.

Comment: А как же это `Суть проблемы в том что после выхода из Фильтра печенек нет`? Проверяте тогда печеньки в запросе, если там нет, то в ответе. Фильтр когда их в ответ ложит до или после `chain.doFilter(request, response);` ? Если после, то jsp их вряд ли увидит

Comment: @Sergey до `chain.doFilter(request, response);`

Коим образом проверять печеньки в запросе?

Comment: А добавить печеньку в запрос можно, сделав свой класс requestwrapper, в который вы сможете добавлять что хотите и подменить им входящий request.

Comment: Ошибочка вышла. cookie в response так просто уже не посмотреть. С другими cookie попутал.

Comment: Лучше освойте CDI Context Dependency injection. Создать класс, внедрять объект этого класса в свои фильтры, сервлеты. В фильтре устанавливаете какие надо свойства, в сервлете | jsp проверяете, переустанавливаете, потом опять в фильтре уже на выходе можно перепроверить.

Comment: в фильтре `res.addCookie(cookie); req.setAttribute("loginCookie", cookie);` в jsp `Cookie loginCookie = (Cookie) request.getAttribute("loginCookie"); if (loginCookie != null) { ... }`